# How to make Jenkins job not to fail upon post-build actions failures?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

There is great build-name-setter-plugin for Jenkins, but in my instance it has staility issue over dependency version marking some builds as failed

> IllegalStateException (Build step 'Changes build name' marked build as failure), while actual build is SUCCESS #62
> https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-name-setter-plugin/issues/62

I cannot upgrade Jenkins or plugins right now.

**How to make Jenkins job not to fail upon post-build actions failures?**

It would be better build name not changed occasionally, than making build as failures while code is OK.